# Sort nodes of AntD DirectoryTree alphabetically

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I am using a directory tree from Ant Design and I want to be able to sort the nodes alphabetically the same way you would on your hard drive with files and folders or the way VS Code sorts files and folders (more specific to my use case). The [Antd DirectoryTree API](https://ant.design/components/tree/) expects an array of nodes like this:

```
const treeData = [
  {
    title: 'parent 0',
    key: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'leaf 0-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        isLeaf: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'leaf 0-1',
        key: '0-0-1',
        isLeaf: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'parent 1',
    key: '0-1',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'leaf 1-0',
        key: '0-1-0',
        isLeaf: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'leaf 1-1',
        key: '0-1-1',
        isLeaf: true,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I generate my treeData array recursively so I'm not exactly sure where I should add sorting logic because I can only process one node at a time and I don't feel like I can step in and sort at each level of the directory during the recursion.

I think I could maybe take the array that is produced after the recursion and map it again, and create an array of arrays, by looking at each node and try to group nodes with the same parent into their own array, then sort each of those arrays, then flatten it... but this might be horribly inefficient. Has anyone tried to sort a AntD DirectoryTree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be pretty simple and I was making it harder than it needed to be because I had used a recursive approach. My full solution is a fair bit more complex but the only part needed for this is a simple call to sort for each recursive call.

```
sort((a, b) => ((a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1));
```